# RadioButtoList não obedece ao SelectedValue selecionado

Tags: c#, asp.net

tenho esse Radiobutton:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlCpfCnpjFornecedorBemNovo" CssClass="cPFCNPJRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <asp:ListItem Text="CPF&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="CNPJ&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

No código tenho isso:

```
rdlCpfCnpjFornecedorBemNovo.SelectedValue = ventBensAquisicao.TipoPessoa.ToString();
```

Acontece que quando o `selectedvalue == 2`, ele não seta, continua com o `CPF` checado e não o `CNPJ`. Tentei outras coisas além do `SelectedValue`, mas nada. Preciso setar de acordo com o que vem do banco, ou seja, 1 ou 2. O que está errado que não funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar a propriedade **SelectedIndex** por exemplo:

```
if (ventBensAquisicao.TipoPessoa == 1)
    rdlCpfCnpjFornecedorBemNovo.SelectedIndex = 0;
else
   rdlCpfCnpjFornecedorBemNovo.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Me deu esse erro: 'rdlCpfCnpjFornecedorBemNovo' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value